# Power BI Dax Measure and return multiple columns

Tags: powerbi

I am filtering the data based on the current logged in user using the below query, now I would like to return some of the columns associated with that user - how to achieve that ?

In the below case I get only 1 value - I tried to return a complete row but it throws me the error "Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value"  - any other way to show multiple columns?

CurrentUserData =
VAR CurrentUserState = CALCULATE(MAX(TimeReport[UserPrincipalName]),FILTER(TimeReport, TimeReport[UserPrincipalName] = USERPRINCIPALNAME()))
RETURN
IF(
SELECTEDVALUE(TimeReport[UserPrincipalName]) = CurrentUserState,
Values(TimeReport[Neukunden_Akquise_Produkte])
)

Reference: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Show-Current-Logged-in-User-data-only/m-p/2219446#M810376

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution and credit goes to @miguelarce
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/RLS-vs-Filter-for-current-user/m-p/329584

Measure1
WhoIsWatching = USERPRINCIPALNAME()
(that is email style usernames, or you can use USERNAME() for windows style users)

[image]

Measure 2
FilterByViewer = IF(selectedvalue(table[email])=[WhoIsWatching],1,0)

[image]

Drag Measure 2 as a filter for visual, select advanced filtering and set it to
"Show items when value IS 1"

[image]